# xsl:sort with imperial measurements

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xslt-1.0

I’m trying to make an xslt file to sort a list for InDesign.

The issue I’m having is trying to get the the list to sort as expected when the size is in imperial rather than metric. To complicate things a little more the size information is contained in a string.

here’s the xslt:

```
<CATEGORY>
  <VERS>
    <xsl:for-each select="VFPData/g_otemp/prodid">
      <xsl:sort select="floor(translate(../desc,$vDigits,''))" />
      <xsl:sort select="translate(../desc,$vAlpha,'')" data-type="number"/>

        <xsl:if test="../inactive != 'true'">
          <code><xsl:value-of select="../prodid" /></code>       
          <name><xsl:value-of select="../desc" /></name>
          <xsl:if test="../priceout != '0.0000'">
            <price><xsl:value-of select="format-number(../priceout, '£0.00')" /></price>
          </xsl:if>
          <xsl:if test="../priceout = '0.0000'">
            <price>P.O.A</price>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </VERS>
</CATEGORY>
```

Which works fine when dealing with metric sizes, however with imperial you see sorting like this:

```
<VERS>
    <code>BM50-100</code>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 16" x 12" x 1"</name>
    <price>£31.82</price>
    <code>BM50-106</code>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 11" x 8 1/2" x 1"</name>
    <price>£24.33</price>
    <code>BM50-123</code>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 2 1/2" x 2" x 1/2"</name>
    <price>£7.42</price>
    <code>BM50-133</code>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 2 3/4" x 2" x 1/2"</name>
</VERS>
```

Where it should be:

```
<VERS>
    <code>BM50-123</code>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 2 1/2" x 2" x 1/2"</name>
    <price>£7.42</price>
    <code>BM50-133</code>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 2 3/4" x 2" x 1/2"</name>
    <code>BM50-106</code>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 11" x 8 1/2" x 1"</name>
    <price>£24.33</price>
    <code>BM50-100</code>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 16" x 12" x 1"</name>
    <price>£31.82</price>
</VERS>
```

Presumably this is happening because the value it's sorting by is the combination of all the numbers in the string, meaning that '2 3/4" x 2" x 1/2"' = 234212 making it indeed larger than '16" x 12" x 1"' (16121).

I've tried to just isolate it to the first number (so between 'Joint ' and '"') and that only really worked if the first number didn't have a fraction.

My other thought is would it be possible to have xslt convert the fraction to a decimal?

How on earth would I go about sorting this using XSLT?

Comment: If you want *any* hope of working out something you will need to post a precise and exhaustive specification in what format your input data comes. Is it always three numbers? Is it always inches? Is it always ` x ` that separates them? What kind of fractions can occur? Do you want a three-level-sort? Also - what kind of XSLT processor are you dealing with? Which extensions does it support?

Comment: I know you've said XSLT 1.0, so I'm not making this an answer, but if you were to move to Saxon and XSLT 2.0 you would be able to take advantage of its "smart alphanumeric" collation sequence, where 2in sorts before 12in - any sequence of digits within the text is sorted as a number. (Incidentally I don't see why your code works with metric units, I suspect that in general it doesn't.)

Answer (score 3):

Disclaimer: This is completely crazy.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="name">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sort" />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- finds the first digit in a name and then extracts exactly thee numerical values -->
  <xsl:template match="name" mode="sort">
    <xsl:param name="rest" select="string(.)" />

    <xsl:variable name="left" select="substring($rest, 1, 1)" />
    <xsl:variable name="by" select="' x '" />

    <xsl:if test="$left">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($left)">
          <xsl:variable name="s1" select="substring-before($rest, $by)" />
          <xsl:variable name="s2" select="substring-before(substring-after($rest, $by), $by)" />
          <xsl:variable name="s3" select="substring-after($rest, concat($s1, $by, $s2, $by))" />
          <xsl:variable name="n1">
            <xsl:call-template name="sanitize"><xsl:with-param name="str" select="$s1" /></xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="n2">
            <xsl:call-template name="sanitize"><xsl:with-param name="str" select="$s2" /></xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:variable name="n3">
            <xsl:call-template name="sanitize"><xsl:with-param name="str" select="$s3" /></xsl:call-template>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat(
            format-number($n1, '000.00'), ' - ',
            format-number($n2, '000.00'), ' - ',
            format-number($n3, '000.00')
          ) " />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="sort">
            <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="substring-after($rest, $left)" />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- converts strings of one full and one factional number ("2 1/4") to a decimal number (2.25) -->
  <xsl:template name="sanitize">
    <xsl:param name="str" />

    <xsl:variable name="bare" select="translate($str, '&quot;', '')" />
    <xsl:variable name="full">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($bare, '/')">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($bare, ' ')" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$bare" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="frac" select="substring-after($bare, $full)" />
    <xsl:variable name="fullNum">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="number($full)">
          <xsl:value-of select="number($full)" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="0" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="fracNum">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$frac">
          <xsl:variable name="q" select="number(substring-before($frac, '/'))" />
          <xsl:variable name="d" select="number(substring-after($frac, '/'))" />
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$q and $d">
              <xsl:value-of select="$q div $d" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
              <xsl:value-of select="number(concat('0.', $q))" /><!-- this is debatable -->
            </xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="0" /></xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="$fullNum + $fracNum" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to

```
<test>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 16" x 12" x 1"</name>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 11" x 8 1/2" x 1"</name>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 2 1/2" x 2" x 1/2"</name>
    <name>Blue-Max Joint 2 3/4" x 2" x 1/2"</name>
</test>
```

gives you

```
<p>016.00 - 012.00 - 001.00</p>
<p>011.00 - 008.50 - 001.00</p>
<p>002.50 - 002.00 - 000.50</p>
<p>002.75 - 002.00 - 000.50</p>
```

You now can use these strings for sorting. Even the three-way sort will work.

But you will need to do some extra work, probably involving the `node-set()` extension function, to actually make it usable in your stylesheet.

Of course this falls apart as soon as the input format changes only slightly.

---

May the above serve as an example for why it is the ultimate bad idea to store formatted, opaque strings in a data format that emphasizes on values and structure.

Comment: +1 for the disclaimer. Also for "May the above serve as an example for why it is the ultimate bad idea to store formatted, opaque strings in a data format that emphasizes on values and structure."